# Why is this Tkinter code giving me an error. When the tutorial does it it works

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working through a youtube tutorial on Tkinter. Everything has been going fine but now I've hit a roadblock. The guy is showing how to use the .get() method to create a label with the text the user enters into an entry when the user hits a button. Save from the names of the label/entry/button, all my code is identical to his in function. It works for him, but I get a nonetype error. Here is a link to the video with a timestamp. Can anyone help me please?

URL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YXPyB4XeYLA
Time: 33:30

```
from tkinter import *
import random

root = Tk()
root.title("Simple Routines")   

Entry1 = Entry(root, width=20, bg='grey').grid(row=2, column=1)

def onClick():
    Name = Entry1.get()
    Label2 = Label(root, text=Name)
    Label2.grid(row=4, column=1)

Label1 = Label(root, text="What Is Your Name?").grid(row=1, column=1)
Button1 = Button(root, text="Enter Your Name", bg='grey', command=onClick).grid(row=3, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have used `.grid()` on your textbox in the same line. In Tkinter if you place your widgets in the same line in which you create them it makes the widgets inaccessible later. I have attached the code for your reference.

```
from tkinter import *
import random

root = Tk()
root.title("Simple Routines")   

Entry1 = Entry(root, width=20, bg='grey')
Entry1.grid(row=2, column=1) # The change

def onClick():
    Name = Entry1.get()
    Label2 = Label(root, text=Name)
    Label2.grid(row=4, column=1)

Label1 = Label(root, text="What Is Your Name?").grid(row=1, column=1)
Button1 = Button(root, text="Enter Your Name", bg='grey', command=onClick).grid(row=3, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Worked like a bomb. I owe you one.

Comment: Can you mark it as correct @Aspiring_Programmer1708?